# Update and specify a key to addToSet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've created a model with a set `matches` in it. However every time I update a document, it just adds the match to `matches`, which results in duplicates. I'm wondering whether there is a method that lets me specify a key, in my case the `matchId`, and if it already exists in the `matches` set it should update that particular object in the set?

**Model**

```
var leagueSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    league: Number,
    matches: [{
        matchId: Number,
        date: Date,
        tournament: String,
        homeName: String,
        awayName: String,
        awayScore: Number,
        homeScore: Number,
        homeLogo: String,
        awayLogo: String
    }]
});
```

**Update Query**

```
var queryData = {'matchId': matchId, 'date': date, 'tournament': tournament, 'homeName': homeTeam, 'awayName': awayTeam, 'awayScore': awayScore, 'homeScore': homeScore, 'homeLogo': homeLogo, 'awayLogo': awayLogo};

League.update({league: leagueId}, {$addToSet: {matches: queryData}})
    .exec(function(err, update) {
});
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK I think this question is a little bit different. In this case we need to update match record if one exists with the same matchId key. Thus it's not duplicate, and your answer isn't a full solution for this question.

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov Got ya, I didn't catch that the first time, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your filter more precise. You can exclude (with [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/ne/)) items in your `matches` array when the `matchId` was found. When your matchId in your matches was found, it will not "find" the document and therefore not update the document. (I know it is confusing!) Your query will look like this:

```
League.update({league: leagueId, 'matches.matchId': {$ne: matchId}}, {$addToSet: {matches: queryData}})
    .exec(function(err, update) {
        // Do something
    });
```